# TASM: Modulo of negative number

Tags: assembly, modulo, tasm

When I do, for example, -1 % 3, I expect the result to be 2.

When I execute the following TASM instructions I get an unexpected result:

```
mov ax, -1
xor bh, bh
mov bl,  3
idiv bl ; ah = FF (I expected 02), al = 00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This web page](http://flylib.com/books/en/2.265.1.32/1/) states that:

> the sign of the remainder is always the same as the sign of the
>   dividend.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Common_pitfalls) has some information regarding pitfalls with a signed remainder.

A possible workaround could be to use `div` instead of `idiv`, and/or keeping track of signs manually.

Comment: it uses, indeed, the fact that you stated regarding the sign of the remainder

Comment: with div, and the signed dividend i get unexpected results in the debugger :S, so the absolute value made it :)